# How to repair an overclocked microsdcard?

Tags: sd-card

I overclocked my raspberry pi 2 myself yesterday. 
However I also increased the sd_freq. Now after a reboot my microsdcard is mounted as read only.
 I have a laptop with linux installed where I can try to repair it.

Here is fsck:

```
fsck /dev/sdb6
fsck von util-linux 2.25.1
e2fsck 1.42.10 (18-May-2014)
fsck.ext2: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden beim Versuch, /dev/sdb6 zu öffnen
Ist das Gerät möglicherweise nicht vorhanden?
```

That's german. The translation of that is:

```
File or directory not found. Failed to open /dev/sdb6
Does the device exist?
```

However if I run `dmesg`, I know that the laptop sees the microsdcard with  errors:

```
    [ 2927.961523] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[ 2928.079252] ntfs: driver 2.1.31 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[ 2928.297070] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
[ 2928.459834] raid6: mmxx1      346 MB/s
[ 2928.516455] raid6: mmxx2      679 MB/s
[ 2928.573186] raid6: sse1x1     114 MB/s
[ 2928.630046] raid6: sse1x2     191 MB/s
[ 2928.686624] raid6: sse2x1     175 MB/s
[ 2928.743233] raid6: sse2x2     343 MB/s
[ 2928.799919] raid6: int32x1    171 MB/s
[ 2928.856656] raid6: int32x2    240 MB/s
[ 2928.913079] raid6: int32x4    282 MB/s
[ 2928.969883] raid6: int32x8    269 MB/s
[ 2928.969891] raid6: using algorithm mmxx2 (679 MB/s)
[ 2928.969896] raid6: using ssse3x1 recovery algorithm
[ 2928.997412] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[ 2929.029731]    pIII_sse  :  4652.400 MB/sec
[ 2929.063063]    prefetch64-sse:  5186.400 MB/sec
[ 2929.063071] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (5186.400 MB/sec)
[ 2929.319852] Btrfs loaded
[ 2929.678921] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 2929.685504] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 2929.692989] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 2929.699864] FAT-fs (sda2): invalid media value (0x39)
[ 2929.699876] FAT-fs (sda2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2929.720715] XFS (sda2): Invalid superblock magic number
[ 2929.733631] FAT-fs (sda2): invalid media value (0x39)
[ 2929.733643] FAT-fs (sda2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2929.752486] MINIX-fs: unable to read superblock
[ 2929.789860] attempt to access beyond end of device
[ 2929.789873] sda2: rw=16, want=3, limit=2
[ 2929.789883] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 2929.798484] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
[ 2929.804082] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

>>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[ 2929.816251] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sda2
[ 2932.646443] audit: type=1400 audit(1430243601.363:38): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=24052 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2947.369673] audit: type=1400 audit(1430243616.083:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=27551 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2993.836057] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 2993.842237] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 2993.849180] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 2993.856179] FAT-fs (sda2): invalid media value (0x39)
[ 2993.856192] FAT-fs (sda2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2993.876759] XFS (sda2): Invalid superblock magic number
[ 2993.890830] FAT-fs (sda2): invalid media value (0x39)
[ 2993.890849] FAT-fs (sda2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2993.907427] MINIX-fs: unable to read superblock
[ 2993.913828] attempt to access beyond end of device
[ 2993.913841] sda2: rw=16, want=3, limit=2
[ 2993.913851] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 2993.920820] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
[ 2993.926967] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

>>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[ 2993.940394] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sda2
[ 3039.949647] audit: type=1400 audit(1430243708.663:40): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=5275 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3039.949668] audit: type=1400 audit(1430243708.663:41): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=5275 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3039.960604] audit: type=1400 audit(1430243708.676:42): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="third_party" pid=5275 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 9265.005906] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 9265.131405] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
[ 9265.131425] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9265.131439] usb 1-2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 9265.131451] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 9265.131463] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 058F0O1111B1
[ 9265.405525] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9265.405824] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 9265.406931] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 9265.438871] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 9266.410221] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multi    Flash Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 9266.411635] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 9266.892135] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 15523840 512-byte logical blocks: (7.94 GB/7.40 GiB)
[ 9266.893257] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 9266.893273] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 9266.894373] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 9266.894385] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 9266.909425]  sdb: [CUMANA/ADFS] sdb1 [ADFS] sdb1
[ 9266.914006] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 9473.723355] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 9478.755845] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 9478.881334] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
[ 9478.881353] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9478.881367] usb 1-2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 9478.881379] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 9478.881391] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 058F0O1111B1
[ 9478.883369] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9478.883796] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 9479.886895] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multi    Flash Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 9479.888376] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 9480.368965] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 15523840 512-byte logical blocks: (7.94 GB/7.40 GiB)
[ 9480.370089] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 9480.370106] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 9480.371325] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 9480.371342] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 9480.390116]  sdb: [CUMANA/ADFS] sdb1 [ADFS] sdb1
[ 9480.396934] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Here are the partition details:

```
    fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 149,1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b890e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 308406271 308404224 147,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       308408318 312580095   4171778     2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       308408320 312580095   4171776     2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 7,4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a4ed9

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           8192   242187   233996 114,3M  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2         245760 15458303 15212544   7,3G 85 Linux extended
/dev/sdb3       15458304 15523839    65536    32M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb5         253952   376831   122880    60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb6         385024 15458303 15073280   7,2G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Gparted also says that there's a problem with superblock...

Trying deroberts suggestion:

```
mknod sdb6 b 8 22
```

This succeeded cause there was no error

Next:

```
e2fsck ./sdb6
e2fsck 1.42.10 (18-May-2014)
e2fsck: Kein passendes Gerät bzw. keine passende Adresse gefunden beim Versuch, ./sdb6 zu öffnen
Möglicherweise ist die Partition nicht vorhanden oder eine Swap-Partition?
```

Translation

```
No fitting device or no fitting address found while trying to open ./sdb6 Maybe the partition doesn't exist or it's a swap partition?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filesystem has gone likely read-only due to same damage, as you've guessed. `fsck` should fix it.

Since you care about your data, and it's a relatively small device, I recommend taking a full disk image first, with something like `cp /dev/sdb /root/sdcard-backup.img` or `pv -pterb -s 7948206080 /dev/sdb > /root/sdcard-backup.img` if you have `pv`.

When you tried to use another machine to run `fsck`, it failed to see the partitions. The kernel log actually leads to an explanation, though its buried and easy to miss:

```
[ 9480.368965] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 15523840 512-byte logical blocks: (7.94 GB/7.40 GiB)
⋮
[ 9480.390116]  sdb: [CUMANA/ADFS] sdb1 [ADFS] sdb1
[ 9480.396934] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I've boldfaced it there. It turns out that Linux looks for CUMANA partition tables before DOS ones and, unfortunately, a CUMANA partition table signature is one byte different—so falsely detecting one is fairly common (<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>256</sub> if the data is random). There was a [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4054) filed on the false detection; the solution from the kernel folks is, basically, that partition format shouldn't generally be enabled.

Your kernel, unfortunately, has `CONFIG_ACORN_PARTITION_CUMANA` enabled. You could switch to a different kernel that does not or recompile your kernel without that option. I've checked the Debian Jessie kernel does not enable that option—so using a Jessie kernel (one option is [Debian Live](http://live.debian.net/)), you should see the partitions and be able to `fsck`.

Once you've done that, your Raspberry Pi should boot again. Depending on the exact corruption some files may need replacing, of course.